# What is overlay network and how does DNS resolution work?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I cannot connect to external `mongodb` server from my `docker swarm` cluster.

As I understand this is because of cluster uses overlay network driver. Am I right?

If not, how does docker overlay driver works and how can I connect to external `mongodb` server from cluster?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Q. How does the docker overlay driver work?**

I would recommend [this good reference for understanding docker swarm network overlay, and more globally, Docker's architecture](http://success.docker.com/article/networking).

This states that:

> Docker uses embedded DNS to provide service discovery for containers running on a single Docker Engine and tasks running in a Docker Swarm. Docker Engine has an internal DNS server that provides name resolution to all of the containers on the host in user-defined bridge, overlay, and MACVLAN networks.
>
> **Each Docker container ( or task in Swarm mode) has a DNS resolver that forwards DNS queries to Docker Engine, which acts as a DNS server.**

So, in multi-host `docker swarm mode`, with this example setup :

[image: architecture]

> In this example there is a service of two containers called `myservice`. A second service (`client`) exists on the same network. The `client` executes two `curl` operations for docker.com and `myservice`.
>
> These are the resulting actions:
>
> - DNS queries are initiated by `client` for `docker.com` and `myservice`.
> - The container's built-in resolver intercepts the DNS queries on `127.0.0.11:53` and sends them to Docker Engine's DNS server.
> - `myservice` resolves to the Virtual IP (VIP) of that service which is internally load balanced to the individual task IP addresses. Container names resolve as well, albeit directly to their IP addresses.
> - `docker.com` does not exist as a service name in the mynet network and so the request is **forwarded to the configured default DNS server**.

Back to your question:

**How can I connect to an external mongodb server form cluster?**

For your external `mongodb` (let's say you have a DNS for that `mongodb.mydomain.com`), you are in the same situation as the `client` in above architecture, wanting to connect to `docker.com`, except that you certainly don't wan't to expose that `mongodb.mydomain.com` to the entire web, so you may have declared it in your internal cluster DNS server.

Then, how to tell docker engine to use this internal DNS server to resolve `mongodb.mydomain.com`?

You have to indicate in your `docker service` task that you want to use an [internal DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#usage), like so:

```
docker service create \
--name myservice \
--network my-overlay-network \
--dns=10.0.0.2 \
myservice:latest
```

The important thing here is `--dns=10.0.0.2`. This will tell the Docker engine to use the DNS server at `10.0.0.2:53` as default if it can not resolve the DNS name in the VIP.

Finally, when you say :

> I cannot connect to external mongodb server from my docker swarm cluster. As I understand this is because of cluster uses overlay network driver. Am I right?

I would say no, as there is a built in method in `docker engine` to forward unknown DNS name coming from `overlay network` to the DNS server you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Francois, thanks for your very helpful reply.
I am experimenting with Swarm as a simpler alternative to K8s but I miss one critical feature: Namespacing. Is there any way to have the DNS lookups include some kind of namespace? Assuming I want to run an application stack several times in the same swarm, I would have to name the services of each stack differntly: app_dev, app_staging, app_production and so on....

Comment: @FabianTe I guess you're right, there is no namespace in swarm as far as I remember. So you would have to name the same application differently. I switched to K8s for production in my professional projects, but swarm is still a good choice for small infrastructures, you'll have to balance the pros/cons of each solution then.