# Dynamically resolving container hostname to an IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

I have several services in a `docker-compose.yml` that need to speak with one another. This isn't the problem since the composer takes care of all the networking internally. However, one of the services requires a whitelist to allow communication to its API. This whitelist has an unfortunate limitation of IPv4 addresses only - it does not resolve hostnames.

I would like to avoid having to define my own custom network and assigning static IP addresses to the containers, keeping it flexible. I have searched up and down and don't see a way to resolve the service names at runtime, or even during the build phase for that matter.

I've tried installing DNS tools and using `dig` but is unable to determine an IP address. This probably has to do with my lack of understanding of how Docker deals with the networking layer.

So my questions are:

- How can I resolve a containers service name either at runtime or during the build phase?
- When building with `docker-compose`, does it assign static addresses to the container or is there a possibility of the containers IP changing after a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar challenge some month ago, and it is possible to obtain what you want (even if I was working on Kubernetes and not with docker-compose).

Docker provides an internal DNS resolution system, as explained in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943101/9306378).
If you hack a little bit with `dig`, you see that the container uses a different DNS IP from your host.

In particular, [launching the Wordpress example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) form the docker-compose documentation you can see it in the following way:

```
mkdir /tmp/test && cd /tmp/test
# create a docker-compose.yaml file and past the example from the link above
docker-compose up -d
# it should be test_default, check it out with `docker network ls`
docker run --rm -it --network test_default ubuntu /bin/bash
```

And then, inside the container type:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y dnsutils
dig wordpress
```

You should obtain something similar to this:

```
root@91e47b426ed3:/# dig wordpress

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> wordpress
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17239
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wordpress.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wordpress.              600     IN      A       172.18.0.3

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Sun Feb 17 19:39:24 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Here you see that the field `SERVER` says `127.0.0.11#53`, that's the internal Docker DNS system in my case. You can check that the address is the one reported (in my case `172.18.0.3`) installing `curl` and reaching it at the port `80`.

With that in mind, you can create a script or a program that periodically performs address resolution, takes the address list the DNS returns for that service and updates your whitelist accordingly.

> How can I resolve a containers service name either at runtime or during the build phase?

Taking Java as example, you can use the [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/InetAddress.html) class that given an URL it gives back a list of IP4 and IP6 addresses (you can filter them using `InetAddressValidator` from the Apache Common library). You can see more [here](https://github.com/Augugrumi/harbor/blob/8bb9ad74faaa920f7b70422fa8fe389f058ee59f/src/main/java/org/augugrumi/harbor/routes/util/InetAddressFilter.java#L20) (that's how I solved the problem). In Linux, there is a specific syscall, [getaddrinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), to obtain a list of IPs given an URL.

> When building with docker-compose, does it assign static addresses to the container or is there a possibility of the containers IP changing after a reboot?

Regarding the second question, docker-compose uses the same logic of `docker build`, so it won't assign static IP addresses or similar. On top of that, if a container crashes and gets restarted, there is the possibility that its IP changes.

Comment: I would give you another upvote if I could. Thank you for taking the time to put this much detail into your answer. I resorted to using a custom networking configuration and assigning the single container that requires a known address to a static IP. I don't like the solution, so I will definitely give yours a shot. Again, thanks for taking the time to write this up! Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help. If you need some help don't mind shooting me a message or otherwise let me know if you open some other Stackoverflow questions! Cheers